# Process doesn't accept parameter?

Tags: c#

I want to start the process with username,password and project_name as parameter, And If the process is already running then don't want to start the same process repetedely.

The process accept all parameters if I don't use the code for avoidance of repetating same process execution.
Below is my code:

```
public SyncConnector(string username, string password, string projectname)
    {
        string thisprocessname = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        if (Process.GetProcesses().Count(p => p.ProcessName == thisprocessname) > 1)
        {
            _proc = Process.Start("doors.exe", "-u " + username + " -P " + password + " -project" + projectname);
        }

        while (_proc != null && !_proc.WaitForInputIdle(1000 * 60))
        {
        }
}
```

This process start when Object is created.means it's call in constructor.
How can I pass the parameter successfully to the process??? 
Thank in Advanced...!

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I do not think I fully understand what behavior you expect and what behavior you are actually getting.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `< 1` (or `== 0`) instead of `> 1`?

Comment: hello @souldeux I want to start the doors.exe application using C# process, if the doors.exe is already running then dont want to start the same application repetadely

Comment: update: Application is started successfully but problem is it can not accept the parameters like username and password.

Answer (score 1):

If the process is already running there's no way to pass "parameters" to it.  It needs to be able to receive information at runtime, e.g. by listening on a socket (like a web service), or reading from a file that it monitors, or via a windows message (rather old-school!).  Assuming doors.exe is something you wrote, it's really up to you what works best.

Comment: Hello Dylan, At the first time when process is not running then i want to pass parameter to that process, But it gives me error,Because of first two line of my code which check the process started or not.

Comment: The problem with that code as others have pointed out is that it should be checking if count is 0, not > 1.  If you fix that you should be able to start up the process with the parameters as intended.

Comment: If count is 0, or < 1 are  not working in my case. I tried both approach but not get what I want

Comment: What is the return value from `GetProcesses(...).Count` ? And what behaviour are you seeing?